# Updating a textured rectangle in Kivy after the texture changes

Tags: python, opengl, kivy

I have a project using Kivy that creates a GL texture from a buffer. The buffer is updated at a regular interval, which changes the texture.

Specifically, the texture is bound to a GLXPixmap, using the GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap extension.

The texture is displayed in a rectangle, like so:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.texture = self.create_texture_from_buffer()

    with self.canvas:
        self.rect = Rectangle(
            size=self.size,
            pos=self.pos,
            texture=self.texture)
```

The first contents of the texture are displayed correctly, but the updated texture is not redrawn automatically when the buffer's contents change.

I've found that reassigning the texture to the rectangle, or calling `canvas.ask_update()` both redraw the texture, but doing so incurs quite the performance penalty, both CPU and GPU.

```
# reassign texture
def update(self, *args):
    self.rect.texture = self.texture
Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0)

# ask update
Clock.schedule_interval(lambda *args: self.canvas.ask_update, 0)
```

Is it possible to render the updated texture without asking for an update on a regular interval?

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to update without performance degradation. Have you found any, sir?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You have to use kivy properties, they make life much easier. Kivy properties are like variables, but you can add a callback(a function that will be called) for when it changes. To start, let's import the ObjectProperty:

```py
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
```

Now to start using properties, **you have to define them at class level**, and your class needs to at some point instantiate EventDispatcher, if your class is a Widget, then it's ok, widgets inherit EventDispatcher, if your class is not inheriting anything, just inherit EventDispatcher(kivy.event.EventDispatcher). So let's say your class is called Abc, then you do it like this:

```py
class Abc(Widget):
    texture = ObjectProperty()  # Here we instantiate the object property

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # This will call the Widget class init so that we can use all the cool widget stuff
        self.texture = self.create_texture_from_buffer()
        # Your canvas code goes here
```

Ok now that we are using a property we can use one of it's special functions, if you define any function called "on_[name of the property]" it will be called when the property changes, and 2 argument will be passed to it, the object which the property changed and the new value, so you define on_texture and make it set the rectangle texture:

```py
class Abc(Widget):
    texture = ObjectProperty()  # Here we instantiate the object property

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # This will call the Widget class init so that we can use all the cool widget stuff
        self.texture = self.create_texture_from_buffer()
        # Your canvas code goes here

    def on_texture(self, instance, new_texture):
        self.rect.texture = new_texture
```

There you go ;)

Comment: I suspect the question behind the question was, whether there's a faster way to update/redraw the rectangle once the pixel buffer is changed.